# SSRS (Sequel Server Reporting Services) subreports returning "Error: Subreport could not be shown.""

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSMS 18.5 (fully patched).

I have a report with three (parameter selections; date which is used to select from a list of available items in the second parameter, which in turn is used to make a selection from the 3rd parameter. This report works! When I call it as a subreport from a master report (using the insert subreport), if there IS data found based on the three (03) parameters I pass it, I get the intended results. If no data is found, I receive the "Error: Subreport cannot be shown." Error. THIS IS OK.

My intent is to call this subreport multiple times with different parameters to list out the different result sets.

My question is how do I condition the subreport call in the master report to not show the error message?

Psuedo code for the visibility option:
   (IIF(returned value = error message), true, false)

I have tried this directly in the subreport properties (Visibility). I have tried putting the subreport call in a rectangle and I have tried putting it in a table / matrix.

There is NO "field" to reference or rowcount that I am aware of. SSMS only allows reference to items at the same level or higher and not lower (the subreport).

A specific expression ( IIF() ) with an explanation would be appreciated. I have read numerous articles and tried them all with no results.

Comment: what if you add the visibility on the actual subreport to be hidden when the row count of your referencing dataset = 0 ?

Comment: Harry, thank-you for the reply.

The subreport is a stand-alone report that is used all day and the list of options in the parameters are limited to options that will return data so there is no way for the report, as a stand-alone report, to not return data. Regardless, I tried your recommendation and it did not have the desired effect when this report is called as a subreport.

I do not want to have to replicate the SQL for each of these reports, there are several, just to call them as subreports.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to trap the error message as a result of calling the subreport and hiding the message.

The specific message is, "ERROR: Subreport could not be shown."

Ideally, the logoc in the "Visibility" section of the call to the subreport would be something like IIF(returned value = "ERROR: Subreport could not be shown.",False,True)

I have also tried putting the subreport call in a rectangle and in a matrix / table.

Any help with specific code and explanation is appreciated!

Comment: so if you run the subreport on it's own using the same parameter that use use for the parent report - does it run or error?

Comment: sometimes.. removing the subreport.. adding it back in and assigning it the correct parameters makes this error go away as well

Comment: Harry, yes, the report runs correctly both as a stand-alone report and as a subreport when passing it parameters that will pull data. This indicates that the parameters, including case, are correct. As a stand-alone report, the parameter values available for the user to select, only list values that will return data. This is done via SQL in the data sets. When using this report as a subreport, the last two parameter selections are not available for selection. There-fore, I am running through all of  the possible selections. This is where some of them *might* have data depending on the date.

Comment: This is late (I was pulled off on a different project), but thank-you for the responses.

The final solution was to run a query prior to running the sub-report (not as efficient as I would like) and only calling the sub-report if data would be returned.